# How To Achieve This Using Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Here is a picture of my data model:
[image]

I have a view where the user can enter a number for weight & reps.  How can I use NSFetchedResultsController (or a better option) to save this as an instance of "Set".

Then I want the user to be able to make multiple "Set" for a particular "Exercise".  The user might choose to do 5 different "Exercise".  I want the total of exercises to be as 1 "Session".

And "Session" will be stored with a timestamp.  That way I can search and bring up data from today, or within 30 days, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up your "Core Data stack" using Apple's templates or other example code (I usually use a custom singleton for this). You will create instances of NSManagedObjectModel, NSManagedObjectContext, and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.

To create new managed objects, I like to use the NSEntityDescription class method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` (really I use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), but that's what it uses).

You can refer to all your objects as NSManagedObject and use `setValue:forKey:`, etc; but I recommend generating custom class files for your entities (Xcode can do this or try mogenerator).

For example (assuming you generate class files and NSManagedObjectContext object is "moc" here):

```
Set *set = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

set.weight = 100;
set.reps = 10;

NSMutableSet *sets = [NSMutableSet set];

[sets addObject:set];

Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

exercise.relationship = sets; // you should name this relationship something like "sets"
```

Then, you can build up exercises and add them to a set and assign that set to the Session's to-many Exercises relationship (again, "exercises" would be a better name).

To save, just call `save:` on your NSManagedObjectContext object.

Also, I noticed that you don't have inverse relationships in your model. It is strongly recommended that you always have inverse relationships.

Comment: Thanks gerry3!  I actually have all the core data stack set up in my app already as I use it to save a user's Routine (which is another entity).  I will rename "Exercise" to "Exercises" and setup inverse relationships.  Its a lot of info so let me reread what you wrote to understand it better.

Comment: Here is my updated data model (http://www.box.net/shared/static/rah3krt9fs.png).  "Routine" is so that a user can create a custom routine choosing from exercises stored in a .plist.  I'm thinking routine should have a relationship with maybe exercises?

Comment: Leave "Exercise" as-is. Entity names are typically single case. My suggestion is to name the to-many relationship from Session to Exercise "exercises". Similarly, name the to-many relationship from Exercise to Set, "sets".

Comment: Thanks gerry3.  Here is the updated model (http://www.box.net/shared/static/n099fzk51k.png).  I still think Routine should have a relationship somewhere in there.

Comment: Correct, it sounds like you would want a to-many relationship from Routine to Exercise (named "exercises", for example).

Comment: Ok perfect. I think this is my final data model: box.net/shared/static/8fttvqh06v.png. I have setup saving the routine and exercises in it, but I'm not sure how to go about saving a set, and putting it inside a particular exercise, and that particular exercise inside a session. thanks.

Comment: I gave an example. You can create an NSMutableSet, add all the Set objects to it and then assign the to-many Set relationship (named "sets") in exercise to your NSMutableSet object.

Comment: Ok, cool ill try that.  Does it make more sense to make premade data in app delegate and then load the code into the table views to make sure all the fetchedresults and MOC are all working, then go ahead and modify the code for user input?

Comment: Dear Gerry, I've started this but still have a couple questions.  I just have a button "Log Set" that adds a set for that exercise.  But I need a way to alloc and init a "Session" entity, like should this automatically happen once every 24 hours or something like that. Or maybe a session can just be 1 day period, like anything recorded in 1 day, will be under a session for that day, example May 1. Then under May 1, I can add exercises and a set per exercise?