# How To Add Data To App To Test Core Data Model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have some discussion in this question regarding my core data model objects, etc : [How To Achieve This Using Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751941/how-to-achieve-this-using-core-data/5752062#5752062)

I want to know if and how I can add data to my App Delegate to mock the data that users will input into the app.  I can then setup all the tableviews and views that use core data and make sure everything is working and hooking up properly.

Then once everything is all set, I can remove this data and switch it to input data from the user.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Data class where you can set the properties of variables or in your case arrays (for displaying data in UITableView). Implement a class method in data class which checks that object has been instantiated or not. If not, it does that. It is something like this :

```
//DataClass.h    

@interface DataClass : NSObject {  

NSMutableArray *nameArray;  
NSMutableArray *placeArray;     

}  
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *nameArray;  
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *placeArray;  
+(DataClass*)getInstance;  
@end  


//DataClass.m  
@implementation DataClass  
@synthesize nameArray;  
@synthesize placeArray;  
static DataClass *instance =nil;  
+(DataClass *)getInstance  
{  
    @synchronized(self)  
    {  
        if(instance==nil)  
        {  

            instance= [DataClass new];  
        }  
    }  
    return instance;  
}
```

Now in your view controller you need to call this method as :

```
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
```

And use the arrays.
This way you can assign data without disturbing AppDelegate, which is a good practice.

Comment: In addition, you may want to consider placing information in a plist file and merely have DataClass.m check to see if a core data store exists, if not, parse that plist file to populate the store. That is essentially how I am doing it for my app and it works well. It makes it really easy to modify information without having to sift through/alter code.

Comment: +1 for @Stunner. I do something similar. It allows me to create data in separate non-code file, which makes for relatively easy editing. And, using NSUserDefaults, I store/check if user has ever run app before. If not, then plist data is imported into Core Data store.