# Collision detection between layers in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a game in Cocos2d. I have enemies that shoot, and have the character shoot. I created a separate layer for the enemies (and their bullets) and a separate layer for the character (and its bullets). The problem is, I don't know how to detect collisions between the two layers. Note, I have the Scene in HelloWorldLayer, and each of the above layers is a child of the scene. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the bullets on the opposite layer from the bullet source, i.e. layer A is the character and the enemy bullets, layer B is the enemy and the character bullets?  Then your collision detection would be on the same layer.

Comment: @highlycaffeniated That sounds GREAT! But the problem is, I don't know how to add a child to a layer from a different class that isn't the Layer's class.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add following lines if your using chipmunks

```
shape->collision_type  = kCollisionTypeParticle;  
cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space_, 
                           kCollisionTypeParticle, 
                           kCollisionTypeParticle, 
                           collisonDetect, 
                           NULL, 
                           NULL, 
                           NULL, 
                           self);
```

Here collisonDetect is a method we need to register as:

```
cpBool collisonDetect(cpArbiter *arb, struct cpSpace *space, void *data) 
{
   <YOUR CLASS> *layer = (<YOUR CLASS> *)data;
   [layer collisonDetect:arb];
   return cpTrue;
}
```

Now here here you will handle rest of the code

```
-(void)collisonDetect:(cpArbiter*)arb
{
   NSLog(@"COLLISION DETECTED");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can detect collision in **Cocos2D** using **CGRectIntersectsRect**.
Your idea regarding creation of separate layers for enemies and bullets might prove to be confusing. In this scenario you should consider going for one layer. You must have had a look on **Ray Wenderlich** of collision detection. If not have a look at [Simple Cocos2d game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial).
If you require more help, let me know.

Comment: I know how to do collision detection with one layer, but how do I do it with more than one?

Comment: No problems. If you want to use two different layers for enemy and bullets,and player and its bullet, you should first create a data class where you can create application variables storing the coordinates you require. In the first layer i.e player layer just pass the required coordinates in a Data class variable. And if you are detecting collision in enemy's bullets layer, Just use the data class variable which contains enemy's bullet coordinates. And same goes for player's bullet and enemy layers.

Comment: Just have a look at [Creating Data class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798649/how-to-add-data-to-app-to-test-core-data-model/5800828#5800828).

Comment: uhhh... I don't understand that, and I don't think I want to figure it out now. I have a question. How do I add a child to a layer that isn't the layer's actual class? Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot add a child of one layer into other. But you can add a layer to the scene which already has a layer. You can create as many objects in the other layer and just add that layer to the layer you want to have child. HUD layer is the perfect example for this. See this : [HUD Layer Cocos2D](https://www.packtpub.com/article/cocos2d-iphone-adding-layers-and-making-simple-pause-screen).

Answer (score 0):

Look into CGRectIntersectsRect.... I haven't done Cocos2D in a LONG time but I do remember using a Scheduler to regularly invoke a method which would detect collisions using the `CGRectIntersectsRect` method...

I had a limited number of sprites on screen and on every pass of the collision detection method I would check to see if any of my enemy sprite frames intersected with my protagonist's frames using `CGRectIntersectsRect`.

This is how I did it:

Step 1:
Implement a method that uses [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to check if the the sprite frames are touching. It could look something like:

```
- (BOOL)detectCollision
{
    CGRect frame1 = someframe;
    CGRect frame2 = anotherframe;

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1, frame2))
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Implement a [Scheduler](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/Scheduler.m?spec=svn1404&r=1404) to invoke your collision detection method every seconds using:

```
[self schedule: @selector(detectCollision) interval:0.25];
```

This way in your game everytime the collisionDetect method is called you can detect collisions. :)